# Transparency/Blending issues with OpenGL ES/iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, transparency, blending

I have a simple 16x16 particle that goes from being opaque to transparent. Unfortunately is appears different in my iPhone port and I can't see where the differences in the code are. Most of the code is essentially the same.

I've uploaded an image to [here](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/262/transparencyfail.jpg) to show the problem

The particle on the left is the incorrectly rendered iPhone version and the right is how it appears on Mac and Windows. It's just a simple RGBA .png file.

I've tried numerous blend functions and glTexEnv setting but I can't seem to make them the same.

Just to be thorough, my Texture loading code on the iPhone looks like the following

```
GLuint TextureLoader::LoadTexture(const char *path)
{
    NSString *macPath = [NSString stringWithCString:path length:strlen(path)]; 
    GLuint texture = 0;

    CGImageRef textureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:macPath].CGImage;
    if (textureImage == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load texture image");
        return 0;
    }

    NSInteger texWidth = CGImageGetWidth(textureImage);
        NSInteger texHeight = CGImageGetHeight(textureImage);

    GLubyte *textureData = new GLubyte[texWidth * texHeight * 4];
    memset(textureData, 0, texWidth * texHeight * 4);

    CGContextRef textureContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(textureData, texWidth, texHeight, 8, texWidth * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(textureImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextDrawImage(textureContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (float)texWidth, (float)texHeight), textureImage);

    CGContextRelease(textureContext);

    //Make a texture ID, bind it, create it
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    delete[] textureData;

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    return texture;
}
```

The blend function I use is glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

I'll try any ideas people throw at me, because this has been a bit of a mystery to me.

Cheers.

Comment: Is the image on the left rendered by the simulator, or is it on actual hardware?

Answer (score 0):

this looks like the standard "textures are converted to premultiplied alpha" problem.

you can use

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

or you can write custom loading code to avoid the premultiplication.

Comment: I have tried glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) and although it seems to work fine when there is only one particle, as soon as there are lots of overlapping ones, the colour gets quite intense/bright.
I'll look into this "premultiplied alpha" thing though.

Answer (score 0):

Call me naive, but seeing that premultiplying an image requires (a*r, a*g, a*b, a), I figured I'd just divide the rgb values by a.

Of course as soon as the alpha value is larger than the r, g, b components, the particle texture became black. Oh well. Unless I can find a different image loader to the one above, then I'll just make all the rgb components 0xff (white). This is a good temporary solution for me because I either need a white particle or just colourise it in the application. Later on I might just make raw rgba files and read them in, because this is mainly for very small 16x16 and smaller particle textures.

I can't use Premultiplied textures for the particle system because overlapping multiple particle textures saturates the colours way too much.